# No such table found error in SqLite database program

Tags: android, sqlite

I have created a SqLite database program but every time it shows the below error

> no such table found

Please let know why this is showing error.

```
public static final String TOWN_ID="_id";
public static final String TOWN_NAME="name";
public static final String DISTT_ID="disttidd";
private static final String TAG="DbaAdapter";
private static final String DATABASE_NAME="mydb";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE="tableetown";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION=2;
private static final  String DATABASE_CREATE="create table "+DATABASE_TABLE+"("+TOWN_ID+" int primary key ,"+TOWN_NAME+" text not null,"+DISTT_ID+" text not null)";
private final Context context;
private DatabaseHelper DBhelper;
private static SQLiteDatabase db;

public tableTown(Context ctx){
    this.context=ctx;
    DBhelper=new DatabaseHelper(context);

}
/* db=DBhelper.getWritableDatabase();
      return this;
 * 
 */
private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
    DatabaseHelper(Context context){
        super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.w(TAG,"Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion +" to "+ newVersion+", which will destroy all old data");
       db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tableTown");
       onCreate(db);
    }
}
public tableTown open() throws SQLException {
    db=DBhelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
public Cursor fetchAllDistt() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Cursor mCursor = db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {TOWN_ID,TOWN_NAME,DISTT_ID}, null, null, null, null, null);

      if (mCursor != null) {
       mCursor.moveToFirst();
      }
      return mCursor;
}
public void close() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    DBhelper.close();
}

}
```

Comment: can you submit logcat output?

Comment: Post your logcat also.

Comment: Try out like this `"CREATE TABLE "+ DATABASE_TABLE +" (" +TOWN_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ," +TOWN_NAME+" TEXT NOT NULL, " +DISTT_ID+" TEXT NOT NULL)";` Add the spaces before the DataType of the fields.

Comment: it shows the same error no such table

Comment: @nitesh: before fetch data have you insert Any data in table????

Comment: i have code to insert data but it is not working error remains the same please tell me if i want to change my data path then how can i do this

Answer (score 0):

inside your on create write this:

```
String DATABASE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + "("
            + TOWN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + TOWN_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
            + DISTT_ID + " TEXT NOT NULL" + " )";
    db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [SQLiteManager](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/04/18/sqlitemanager-plugin-for-eclipse/) for such cases.

Put a break point in onCreate, make sure the line is executed.
Then, switch to DDMS view and use the plugin to find out what is wrong.

Hope this helps, Yaron

Answer (score 0):

If your app is crashing in onUpgrade then Volodymyr Yatsykiv answered your question. Try to change it to

`@Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) 
    {
       db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " +DATABASE_TABLE);
       onCreate(db);
    }`

and make sure to use DATABASE_TABLE instead of hardcode table name.

Please provide full log if its still crashing.

Best wishes.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
String DATABASE_CREATE="create table "+DATABASE_TABLE+"("+TOWN_ID+" integer primary key ,"+TOWN_NAME+" text not null,"+DISTT_ID+" text not null);";
```

put ";" to the end of DATABASE_CREATE string.

look for this:

```
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE="tableetown";
```

and this:

```
db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tableTown");
```

table name is different!

Comment: (1) no such table: tableetown again

Comment: try reinstall your application

Comment: i am developing the project then how can i reinstall my app

Comment: Settings - Applications - Manage applications - choose your app - uninstall it.
Then build (compile) your project to emulator or phone again.

Comment: you change database version, but table name is different!